# How to Supress access your private key dialog UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp, certificate, httpclient

I have added certificate following way , but it asking dialog for "Do you want to allow to access your private key very API call , how ignore dialogs in `UWP`

**Code :**

```
await CertificateEnrollmentManager.UserCertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync(
               pfxcert,
               password,
               ExportOption.Exportable,
               KeyProtectionLevel.NoConsent,
               InstallOptions.None,
               "TEST");
  var myFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
    CertificateQuery certQuery = new Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.CertificateQuery();
    certQuery.FriendlyName = "TEST";    // This is the friendly name of the certificate that was just installed.
    IReadOnlyList<Certificate> certificates = await Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.CertificateStores.FindAllAsync(certQuery);
    var client = new HttpClient(certificates[0]);
```

It always showing dialog for allow access 
**dialog :**

[image]

Comment: I have attempted to show this dialog with your code, but I could not  reproduce, and  I could not pass the  `certificates[0]` parameter  to `HttpClient` construction method. Could you show more code ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT try some API with Certificate authentication